# ModuleNotFound: azure.core.rest devops azure cli task

Tags: azure-devops

We have a devops pipeline which has an azure cli task that triggers and adf pipeline. All was working untill last friday but now the same task started giving error: ModuleNotFound: azure.core.rest.

The azure cli task looks like this:

```
az login --service-principal --username $(test-service-principle-id)  --password $(test-service-principle-password) --tenant $(TENANT_ID)
    
 az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
    
 $runId=az datafactory pipeline create-run --factory-name test-adf  --name "pl_load_training_data" --resource-group test-rg --query "runId" --output tsv
```

I have added azure-core to requirements.txt and running `pip list | grep auzre-core` also list that it is installed.

Here is the trace:

[image]

Comment: I think the issue comes from there are multiple python version in your machine, and you only install the module in one of them.

Comment: The issue show that on specific version didn't find module, it may not be installed there.